# How to convert "world coordinates to object coordinates" in OpenGL ES for android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

in OpenGL ES 1, I have a Rubic cube that consists of 27 smaller cubes. i want a rotation which causes a particular small cube becoming exactly in front of the viewpoint. so i need two vectors. one is the vector that comes from the origin of the object to that particular cube. and another is the vector that comes from origin to the viewpoint. then the cross product of them gives me the axis of the rotation and the dot product gives me the angle.

but i cant convert the (0,0,1) -which is the vector that comes from the origin to the viewpoint in world coordinate- to object coordinates.

how can i do that? how can i convert  "world coordinates to object coordinates"?

Comment: Is this ES 1.x or 2.0? The answer's going to end up relating to how you specify the transformation into OpenGL, and you'll be using completely different routes depending on the API.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to rotate the camera around than it is rotating the object in front of a stationary camera.
You can do what you asked for by placing the camera at the origin (center) of the rubic cube, giving it the opposite direction from the small cube, and than translating z backwards.

I know it doesn't answer the question in the title, but I think it's a simpler solution. (As for your question, I keep world and object coordinates same, and set the object scale as needed when rendering).